# Another unique way to say "other end of the spectrum"

Tags: phrase-requests

Something like "on the other hand" but unique or with an interesting twist.

Comment: *The other extreme*?

Comment: What's the context? Sometimes you can use metaphors like "on the other side of the fence" (not a serious example) but the context has to fit the metaphor.

Comment: +1 Good question. Let me think. (If I'm not carried away by the other posts, that is.)

Answer (score 2):

I use the following:

"It is the other way around Michelle. What happens is .....(my opinion that contradicts yours)".

Answer (score 0):

"On the contrary" or "contrariwise" may suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Since a phrase is asked for, not a single word, I would suggest "or, it could be the complete opposite".  This is very similar to 'on the other hand' but more extreme.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps **[on the other side of the coin](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/the+other+side+of+the+coin)** (or *on the **flip** side of the coin*)

> a different and usually opposite view of a situation that you have previously talked about *The other side of the coin is that fewer working hours means less pay*

Answer (score -1):

"Conversely" is nice and concise... and it sums up the what you want to say in one word, (though I appreciate you are asking for a phrase).

Here's its meaning and a contextual example:

[image]

I found a latin phrase for everyday use in English, that acts LIKE a synonym for conversely: "**mutatis mutandis**", but its meaning as 'the changes have been made' requires subtle usage:

Example: The men's changing rooms can, **mutatis mutandis**, be used by the women.

It can be understood as meaning "acknowledging the difference between the two" or (more succinctly) as "acknowledging differences". ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutatis_mutandis))

Comment: **Mutatis mutandis** is not a synonym for conversely. See http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mutatis%20mutandis

Comment: http://thesaurus.com/browse/conversely - you'll see it right there (why so hostile? I've provided my evidence FOR, where's yours AGAINST? not in your link that's for sure.)

Comment: **No.** **No.** Firstly, Thesaurus.com is not an authoritative way to decide if two words are synonyms. He cited a dictionary definition which is obviously very different from any definition of _conversely_. Secondly, _mutatis mutandis_ is not in fact listed as a synonym for _conversely_ on that page. It is listed under "More words related to conversely" as a synonym for _vice versa_ (which, by the way, is also wrong; they mean different things). Answering questions on this exchange is not a matter of Googling for the answer with no prior expertise.

Comment: *Conversely* has its uses. *At the other end of the spectrum* is a different ball game.

Comment: I gave sources, explanations, warnings about usage, examples and interpretations for the use of a phrase with a unique or interesting twist, for something like "on the other hand". 2 down votes. really? 'no prior expertise' quickly altered from the previous 'not qualified for this site'... The words "pathetically pedantic" spring to mind.

Comment: You gave your source as thesaurus.com, which is not at all a definitive source for whether two words are synonyms. Your warning was reasonable, but _mutatis mutandis_ is not like a synonym for _conversely_. _Mutatis mutandis_ indicates that something is similar to what you're comparing it to, with allowances for minor, non-integral differences; _conversely_ indicates that something is specifically the opposite of what you're comparing it to. Your example isn't really a good example, since it doesn't fall with common usage; see historical examples from the OED.

Comment: @Backgammon: What you have stated here is repetative, edited for politeness, sometimes incorrect, plain wrong in places and further, I simply don't agree.

Comment: @Kris that's actually very clever, nicely done.

Comment: Please note where I've given wrong information. You may disagree, but you are objectively wrong on defending _mutatis mutandis_ as a synonym for conversely. Repetitiveness and editing have no effect on the correctness or incorrectness of what I've said. Spelling is also probably important for a English Language SX.